# Change sample rate in OggOpus metadata (48 kHz to 44.1 kHz) without re-encoding

Tags: audio, metadata, ogg, opus

I have many Opus encoded files that play high pitched in any player because somewhere in the metadata they are marked as 48 kHz (or unmarked but assumed to be 48 kHz) but are in fact 44.1 kHz. If I put them in Audacity, and change to 44.1 kHz, they sound correct, but I don't want to re-encode them in a lossy format, or export as FLAC in the correct rate as they are hours long and would take too much space (I keep them on the cloud with limited space).

How can I change the metadata to tell every audio player to play them as 44.1 kHz without re-compressing them.

I'm using Debian 12, I did `strings audio.ogg | grep 48` and `grep 48000` but could not find any particular place in the file which states what sample rate the audio should be played at.

Comment: ( https://opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.7/structOpusHead.html ) lists the header structure. looks like `input_sample_rate` is the one you want. Looks like 1byte+1byte+(32bytes?) and then the sample rate as a 32-unsigned-int. Maybe open up a copy of one using a hex editor.

Comment: @Yorik thanks for the doc, seems it's not possible/(conventional). The doc states Opus files should be 48kHz. I dug through my Opus files, and some example files I made with different sample rates using 2 of the encoders Audacity supports for opus (ffmpeg and other other one). Seems that even if its made in other sample rates, they just get converted to 48 kHz with the pitch/speed adjusted.

Comment: I did find the actual location of the uint_32 but its closer to the end of the file and might be a coincidence too that its `0000 BB80`

Opening them in Audacity or VLC, the codec still states 48 kHz even though I exported in 44.1 and 22050 (just to make it easy to find in the hex editor later)
Guess I'll just re-export these into FLAC's and forget the whole thing

What's the convention for this question, I want it to be kept for others to find as I found this info hard to find initially, so don't want to delete it (but it doesnt really have an answer)

Comment: I think "you can't" is an answer. Move your comments to an answer and then accept it.